# Allocating dynamic memory to a Structures Array

Tags: c, memory

I'm trying to answer an homework assignment I have where I need to ask for "n" coordinates and then build an Array of struct coordinates with that size.
Each coordinates struct have 2 variables from type double.

I tried getting the input of n from the user and check with an if statement that it first bigger then 0 to avoid any failure

```
printf("Enter amount of coordinates:\n");
scanf_s("%d", &n);
if (n > 0) {
    coordinates cordArray = (coordinates *)malloc(cordArray * sizeof(n));
```

}

Expected is that after getting the n value from the user, to allocating the right size to the structs array.
The error I get is 
"Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E0415   no suitable constructor exists to convert from "coordinates *" to "coordinates"

Comment: Does your assignment states that you have to use `malloc`? This is an old method of allocation from C. In C++ `new` is preferred.

Comment: Yes, we must use malloc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

probably

> ```
> coordinates cordArray = (coordinates *)malloc(cordArray * sizeof(n));
> ```

must be replaced by

```
coordinates * cordArray = (coordinates *)malloc(sizeof(coordinates) * n);
```

because you assign a `coordinates` with a `coordinates *` and `cordArray` is unknown and even it is is may be not convertible to a `size_t` (you do not give its definition)

---

BTW you are in C++, why do you use a C array, you can allocate it by *new* allowing to have the constructor of *coordinates* called for each entry or better use a `std::vector` allowing to change the size, access to the size etc

---

About your remarks, that program compile and run :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct { 
  double x;
  double y;
}coordinates;

int main()
{
  printf("Enter amount of coordinates:\n");

  int n;

  if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1)
    puts("invalid number");
  else if (n <= 0)
    puts("expected a positive number");
  else {
    coordinates * cordArray = (coordinates *) malloc(sizeof(cordArray) * n);

    if (cordArray == NULL)
      printf("cannot allocate memory, probably %d too large\n", n);
    else {
      int i;

      for (i = 0; i < n; i++) { 
        printf("Please enter coordinates for coordinates #%d:\n", i + 1);
        if (scanf("%lf%lf", &cordArray[i].x, &cordArray[i].y) != 2){
          puts("invalid values");
          return -1;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note this is C code, why do you used tag C++ ?

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ g++ -pedantic -Wall -Wextra c.cc
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Enter amount of coordinates:
2
Please enter coordinates for coordinates #1:
1 2
Please enter coordinates for coordinates #2:
3 4
```

Comment: if I may ask another question regarding this,
after I allocated the memory i needed I now need to access that struct array in a for loop and get the input for x and y but I can't access that cordArray now.
From what I read, if I want to access the x and y values it need to be like this
codArray[[i].x  /  codArray[[i].y 
but I can't access the struct of cordArray in anyway.

Comment: what do you mean "I can't access that cordArray now" ? after the _malloc_ you can access any entry in it

Comment: @YakirMalka I don't know how the struct `coordinates` looks but it will be probably something like `cordArray[i].x` and `cordArray[i].y`.

Comment: @YakirMalka I edited my answer, warning if _coordinates_ does not contains on integer/float because using _malloc_ the constructor is **not** called for each element

Comment: I will explain again.
I have "n" number of coordinates that I need to gather from a user into array of structures.
Meaning, after I assigned the memory above, I need now to run until "n" in a for loop and insert the coordinates for x and y for each struct in the array.
So from what I understand, I have the for loop running until "n" that's not a problem, after that I need to scanf the input into the x and y,

Comment: so I thought the scanf would look like this
 from what  I thought it should look like this
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
printf("Please enter coordinates for coordinates #%d:\n", i + 1);
scanf_s("%lf%lf", &cordArray[i].x, &cordArray[i].y);
}

Comment: @YakirMalka yes this is that, what is the problem ? but I encourage you to check the result of scanf to check it is 2. Why `scanf_s` (non standard) rather than `scanf` ?

Comment: to your question why I'm using that way - that is the homework assignment..
anyway, I'm getting this message:
Error (active) E0349 no operator "[]" matches these operands

So I don't know what I'm doing wrong in here.
and scanf getting me an error with the VS and asking to use scanf_s

Comment: did you correct the code to have `coordinates * cordArray = ...` ? WHat is the definition of _coordinates_ ? it is strange to have a 's' at the end of the name

Comment: @bruno , yes I did fix that
and that's the struct itself -- 
typedef struct {
 double x;
 double y;
}coordinates;

Comment: @YakirMalka I think this is the point when you have to create a new question, containing [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We cannot help you without seeing what exactly you did so far.

Comment: I will open a new question regarding this , thanks.

Comment: @YakirMalka I edited my answer with a full program corresponding to your remarks

Answer (score 0):

@bruno has showed the correct way to allocate memory using `malloc`.
However, this can be done even simpler with help of operator `new[]` which automatically calculates amount of required memory.

```cpp
coordinates *cordArray = new coordinates[n];
```

To free the memory, use operator `delete[]`.

```
delete[] cordArray;
```

Another advantage of the C++ way of allocation is that it calls constructors for newly created objects. (If they have any constructors, that is.)

Comment: I also speak about _new_ and constructor ;-)

Comment: I need to use malloc function to dynamic allocate memory, thats the assignment :(

Comment: @YakirMalka Well, I shouldn't be surprised. It's normal that teachers still live in 20th century ;)

Comment: @bruno Sorry, it wasn't marked as code and I missed it.